# How do I use NGROK to gather post data and send it automatically to a .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pycharm, ngrok

Currently needing help doing the following:

Take the highlighted data from the POST Request(s) Summary *See Image* and use python/ pycharm to load them into .csv file as they come in.

Each of these post requests will be a different link and I just need them to be automatically sent to the .csv file using python/ pycharm.

I am using TWILIO to send the post requests to NGROK.

THANK YOU SOOO MUCH

Answer (score -1):

First of all Ngrok cant be used to gather data, its a tunneling tool that exposes your local server to the internet. To achieve what you need you need to evaluate the POST request and parse the so that you can fetch the fields you need. Post the code you have to get further assistance.

Comment: Amazing feedback. I am using integromat to send the information to NGROK Local server. I am not sure what code i need to parse it out